# I have a backup error on SQL SERVER 12, how can i solve

Tags: sql-server, backup

I have a backup issue in sql server. Backup plans are stopping working in first step of backup job.

this is the error description

Backup.LOG,,,The job failed.  The Job was invoked by User sa.  The last step to run was step 1 (LOG)

Server is have 500 gb of free storage. There is no disk error or low memory warning.

i have checked backup plans and checked if there is a read only protection on the disk but there isnt.

Comment: By "SQL Server 12" I assume you mean SQL Server 2014?

Comment: When you checked the logs for the agent task, what was the error? It will tell you more than just "The job failed".

Comment: I cant find detail. SQL Server 2014 just gives me this error. 

EXECUTE master.dbo.xp_create_subdir N'D:\Backup\LO...".: 6% complete  End Progress

Comment: Why are you using SQL Server to create a directory..? This is starting to smell like an [XY problem](//xyproblem.info).

Comment: Backup plan is creating directory. Foldering databases in another disk.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it. Job Activity monitor is not detailed and it says only "An error occurred". I found the error in this directory:

```
C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL12.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\Log
```

One of the databases are offline and SQL Server can't back it up. I deleted the offline database from the backup settings and it's working.